# Get stream of local image. Windows phone 8

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, stream

I have image ( /Assets/Cat.png ). 
I need to get stream of this image. I have tried some ways, but all of them were unsuccessfully. What should i do?

Comment: Stream as in the file stream or the pixel buffer stream?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the stream of the image use this

```
Stream myStream = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Cat.png", UrKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Stream;
```

Comment: GetResourceStream returns null, unfortunally(.

Comment: It will be null in case the Uri is not proper, just check that the Uri you are giving is right and the file does exist. I have tested this and is working pretty well for me. If it still does not work may be you can share the solution with me

Comment: omfg, Uri was starting from / , that's why this was not working. Thx.